# Does the site statistic "%answered" take into account deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, site-stats

One site statistic available through [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) or area51 is the % answered.  On some sites, many unanswered questions get deleted after a month (if downvoted) or after a year (otherwise).  Are those questions accounted for in the %answered?

For example, on Expats, [it appears 70% of questions are deleted](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/368/6) due to not getting answers (NB: the 70% estimate may be in error).  The answer rate is supposed to be 84%.  The two numbers do not really compute.  How is this answer rate calculated when many questions get deleted, such as [under the `RemoveDeadQuestions` and `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` directives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/172266)?

I think it matters, because a site where most questions get no attention at all (lots of [tumbleweed](/questions/tagged/tumbleweed)?) does not provide a good user experience.  If, for example, only people who answer a question upvote the question, then the answer rate of questions will trend toward 100%, even if only a minority of questions get answered at all.

Answer (score 7):

Deleted questions are not taken into account (on Ask Different, we have over 40k of deleted questions, which would skew our numbers likewise), but a good question is: what exactly *does* % answered mean?

I've written a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/941400/answered) to find out; logical candidates are:

- questions with answers
- questions with upvoted answers (i.e. the criterion for not ending up on the 'unanswered' tab)
- questions with upvoted or accepted answers

However, none of the three percentages (84.3, 79.45, 74.52) match the 82% shown for Ask Different on stackexchange.com; it's somewhere in between. For Expatriates, [all percentages are significantly lower](https://data.stackexchange.com/expatriates/query/941400/answered) than the advertised 84%. I don't think it can be explained by a sudden surge of answers since last Sunday when SEDE was updated.

Comment: I've also tried what happens when we limit to questions with score >= 0 or > 0, but without success: https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/941415/answered-for-questions-scoring-x-or-more?minQScore=1

Comment: The following seems to match the Apple percentage: https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/941523

Comment: ... and it does for a dozen others I've checked. Well done!